# asp.net core - login page doesn't show error message

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a problem, i new with asp.net core and i try to build Login page (after i finish to build sign up page that add new row to db with the correct information).

my problem is when i click on login button with the wrong details so i don't see the error message (LoginError) only after i click on login button again i see the LoginError message (from TempData), why?

is the right way? if not i will happy to try another way.

Login cshtml page:

```
@page
@model AutomationTool.Pages.Login.IndexModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Login</h1>

<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="user.UserEmail"></label>
    <input asp-for="user.UserEmail" class="form-control" />
    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="user.UserEmail"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="user.Password"></label>
    <input asp-for="user.Password" class="form-control" />
    <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="user.Password"></span>
</div>
<div>
    @Model.LoginError
</div>
<div>
    @Model.Message
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
```

Login cshtml.cs page:

```
namespace AutomationTool.Pages.Login
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
    private readonly IUserData userData;

    [BindProperty]
    public User user { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string LoginError { get; set; }


    public IndexModel(IUserData userData)
    {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        ModelState.Remove("User.Id");
        ModelState.Remove("User.FirstName");
        ModelState.Remove("User.LastName");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TempData["Message"] = "All fields required!";
            return Page();
        }

        if (!userData.VerifyLogin(user.UserEmail, user.Password))
        {
            TempData["LoginError"] = "Something wrong try again!";
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
    }
}
}
```

thanks!

Comment: As you didn't reach the `ModelState.IsValid` I think your model doesn't have Validation Attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here your `Message` and `LoginError` parameters have been `read many times` instead of once, so you should use `[BindProperty] or [ViewData]` instead of [TempData] to bind these two parameters.

The difference between them, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52066637/12884742).

Chang your code like this:

```
 public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
    private readonly IUserData userData;

    [BindProperty]
    public User user { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]//[ViewData]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]//[ViewData]
    public string LoginError { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(IUserData userData)
    {
        this.userData = userData;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        ModelState.Remove("User.Id");
        ModelState.Remove("User.FirstName");
        ModelState.Remove("User.LastName");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Message = "All fields required!";
            return Page();
        }

        if (!userData.VerifyLogin(user.UserEmail, user.Password))
        {
            LoginError = "Something wrong try again!";
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test result:
[image]